# How to link against API package in ROS from a catkin package (as a user application)

Tags: ros, catkin, package, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am working on KUKA youbot. To drive this robot I have to use an API package provided by Kuka.
To use this APIs I need to make a ROS based user application (A ros package) which links against the API package.

The API package contains other packages and folders such as 'lib'(including libsoem.a , libYouBotDriver.a and libYouBotDriver.so ), 'config', 'build', 'bin', 'soem'...
My problem is that I don't know how to link my user application (the main package) to this API package?
I use catkin workspace for making the main package. Later I will expand my package by applying other packages such as kinect camera to receive some data and command the youbot from main package and APIs to control it.

At this step I would appreciate it if you tell how I can link a ros package (a user application) against a package contains some APIs which can control the movements of the robot.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198777/how-to-link-against-api-package-in-ros-from-a-catkin-package-(as-a-user-application)/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The manufacturer's documentation should describe how to link against their package.

If you're trying to link a catkin package against another catkin package, you can simply add that package as a dependency in your package.xml and add it as a component to `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` in your cmakelists.

If you're trying to link a catkin package against a system package, you should look into the cmake `find_package()` command.

It looks like there are already ROS wrappers for the youbot; you might want to check those out as well: http://wiki.ros.org/youbot_driver and http://wiki.ros.org/youbot_common

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-03**:
Thanks for your answer. Would you please tell me briefly what a system package is and how do I discriminate a system package with a catkin package? Dose a system package is the same as a repository

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-04**:
A system package is a package that is outside of the ROS ecosystem; boost and libsensors are both examples of system packages.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-12**:
Thanks for helping me but I am facing with this error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named node_pkg/main.ccp.
I explained my problem in this topic:
http://answers.ros.org/question/199276/rosrun-couldnt-find-executable-named-error-for-youbot/

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-12**:
unfortunately, The manufacturer's documentation does not describe how to link against their package.